# Why can not the condition expression be two lines in while loop?

Tags: r

There is a  while loop,when i write it in just one line ,it is ok

```
while (money<100*i*(exercise_price-premium)+per_trade+i*per_contract)
{"omitted"}
```

When i write it as two lines ,something is wrong.

```
while (cost<-100*i*(exercise_price-premium)+per_trade+i*per_contract;
money<cost)
{"omitted"} 


Error: unexpected symbol in:
"while (cost<-100*i*(exercise_price-premium)+per_trade+i*per_contract
money"
```

How can i revise it as two lines?i think it is better for tow lines to sophisticated expression .

Comment: and use spaces. `cost<-100` is not `cost < -100`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I think he meant to assign.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman fair enough, then use `cost <- 100`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition inside a `while` has to be an expression evaluating to a true/false result. The pair of lines

```
cost<-100*i*(exercise_price-premium)+per_trade+i*per_contract;
money<cost
```

is *two* statements/expressions, not a single one. But you can get the latter, by wrapping your code inside curly braces `{}`:

```
while({
    cost <- 100*i*(exercise_price-premium)+per_trade+i*per_contract
    money < cost
})
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're going for?

```
cost <- 100*i*(exercise_price-premium)+per_trade+i*per_contract
while (money<cost)
{"omitted"}
```

Comment: That's not quite the same, because this results in `cost` being evaluated only once, while in the original code it would be (re-)evaluated for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: @HongOoi Good point.  They probably wanted something closer to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use curly brackets to group expressions in while condition.

```
# This doesn't work
i <- 0
while(k <- i+1; k< 20) i <- i+1
# but this works
while({k <- i+1; k< 20}) i <- i+1
```